# What is wrong in this Java JDBC program?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

What is wrong in this Java JDBC program?

I have written a method that takes a ResultSet and prints all of its records.

My SQL query is:

```
Set @counter := 0, @counterQty := 0, @counterAvb := 0, @counterIss := 0, @counterRep := 0 ,@counterDes := 0;
Select *
From (SELECT 
       (Select (@counter := (@counter + 1) ) ) 'Sr.No.',
       testt.BookName,
       testt.BookQty,
       testt.Code, 
       testt.Available, 
       testt.Issued, 
       testt.Repair, 
       testt.Destroyed,
       (@counterQty := @counterQty + testt.BookQty ) TotalQty,
       (@counterAvb := @counterAvb + testt.Available ) TotalAvb,
       (@counterIss := @counterIss + testt.Issued ) TotalIss,   
       (@counterRep := @counterRep + testt.Repair ) TotalRep,   
       (@counterDes := @counterDes + testt.Destroyed ) TotalDest
     From (Select a.b_name BookName, a.b_qty BookQty, a.b_acc_id Code,
            SUM(case  when b.status='A' then 1 else 0 end) as Available,
            SUM(case  when b.status='I' then 1 else 0 end) as Issued, 
            SUM(case  when b.status='R' then 1 else 0 end) as Repair, 
            SUM(case  when b.status='D' then 1 else 0 end) as Destroyed      
          From tbl_book_info a left join tbl_books b on a.b_acc_id = b.accid 
          GROUP BY a.b_name, a.b_qty, a.b_acc_id order by a.b_acc_id
     )testt
)Main;
```

When I am executing this query in MySQL Workbench, it returns:

```
    +--------+--------------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
    | Sr.No. | BookName     | BookQty | Code  | Available | Issued | Repair | Destroyed | TotalQty | TotalAvb | TotalIss | TotalRep | TotalDest |
    +--------+--------------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
    |      1 | Java book    |       3 | 10001 |         0 |      0 |      1 |         2 |        3 |        0 |        0 |        1 |         2 |
    |      2 | Cpp Book     |       5 | 10002 |         3 |      1 |      0 |         1 |        8 |        3 |        1 |        1 |         3 |
    |      3 | Cpp 1.17     |       5 | 10003 |         3 |      1 |      0 |         1 |       13 |        6 |        2 |        1 |         4 |
    |      4 | Visual Basic |       4 | 10004 |         4 |      0 |      0 |         0 |       17 |       10 |        2 |        1 |         4 |
    +--------+--------------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
    4 rows in set (0.25 sec)
```

But when I am executing this query in Java and printing all data of ResultSet, it returns like:

```
        1       2               3         4         5           6       7         8         9           10          11        12          13                    
    +--------+--------------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
    | Sr.No. | BookName     | BookQty | Code  | Available | Issued | Repair | Destroyed | TotalQty | TotalAvb | TotalIss | TotalRep | TotalDest |
    +--------+--------------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+

       0       Cpp 1.17          5       10003          3     1          0          1          0          0          0          0          0

       0       Cpp Book          5       10002          3     1          0          1          0          0          0          0          0

       0       Java book         3       10001          0     0          1          2          0          0          0          0          0

       0       Visual Basic      4       10004          4     0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0

    +--------+--------------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

My question is:

**Why it is giving zero (0) for column 1,9,10,11,12 and 13**

## Tables structure

```
create table if not exists tbl_book_info(
    b_acc_id int(5) not null auto_increment,
    b_name varchar(50) not null,
    b_qty int(2) not null,
    b_type varchar(30) not null,
    b_auth1 varchar(50) not null,
    b_auth2 varchar(50),
    b_pub varchar(50) not null,
    b_pages int(4) not null,
    b_rack int(5) not null,
    b_price  Decimal(6,2) not null,
    b_about text,
    primary key(b_acc_id)
);

create table if not exists tbl_books(   
    accid int(5) references tbl_book_info.b_acc_id,
    accno int(3),
    status varchar(1) default "A",
    primary key(accid,accno)
);
```

My code to print this:

```
Connection con = getDbConnObj();
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery( sql );
printRsLast(rs);

public void printRsLast(ResultSet rs){
/*  +---1----+-----2--------+----3----+--4----+-----5-----+----6---+---7----+-----8-----+-----9----+----10----+----11----+----12----+-----13----+
    | Sr.No. | BookName     | BookQty | Code  | Available | Issued | Repair | Destroyed | TotalQty | TotalAvb | TotalIss | TotalRep | TotalDest |
rs= +--------+--------------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+
    |      1 | Java book    |       3 | 10001 |         1 |      0 |      0 |         2 |        3 |        1 |        0 |        0 |         2 |
    |...........................................................................................................................................|
    |...........................................................................................................................................|
    |...........................................................................................................................................|
    +--------+--------------+---------+-------+-----------+--------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----------+   */


    String separator = "          ";
    try{
        rs.beforeFirst();
        int n=0;

        p("$$$ RS Attr. are : \n\n Sr.No. | BookName     | BookQty | Code  | Available | Issued | Repair | Destroyed | TotalQty | TotalAvb | TotalIss | TotalRep | TotalDest , Row are...\n");

        while(rs.next()){
            n++;
            String nm , m;

            m = rs.getInt(1)+ separator + rs.getString(2)+ separator + rs.getInt(3)+ separator + rs.getInt(4)+ separator + rs.getInt(5)+ separator + rs.getInt(6)+ separator + rs.getInt(7)+ separator + rs.getInt(8)+ separator + rs.getInt(9)+ separator + 
                rs.getInt(10)+ separator + rs.getInt(11)+ separator + rs.getInt(12)+ separator + rs.getInt(13);
            p(m+"\n");
        }
        p("\nTotal Rows = "+n);
    } catch(Exception e){
        p("\n!!! Excep in 'printRsLast(ResultSet rs), msg = '"+e.getMessage());
    }
}

public Connection getDbConnObj() {
    // Creating 'Connection' class' Reference Variable ...
    Connection con = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarydb";
    String dbUname = "root";
    String dbPass = "";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, dbUname, dbPass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        con = null;
    } finally {
        return con;
    }
}
```

I tried both the things ...

1)

```
sql = "Set @counter := 0...";
    rs = st.execute(sql);       //  Execute this 'Set @counter...' Stmt first Than

    sql = "Select * From...";
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);  //  Executing this 'Select * from...' Stmt to get the Tabular Data...
    printRsLast(rs);
```

2)

```
  sql = "Set @counter := 0...
            ....
            ....
            )Main;" 
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);  //  Executing these Entire Stmt to get the Tabular Data...
    printRsLast(rs);
```

**But Unfortunately , Both did not worked for me...**

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your Java code. For example the query is missing from your Java code, and it is likely that is where your problem is. The problem is likely from your use of variables.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using a simplified example. [This code](https://pastebin.com/A2mXmUUR) works fine for me. As @Mark says, please [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: If the answer I provided didn't work, please explain why not.  Did it give the wrong results (and if so, what were they)?  Did it give an exception (and if so, what exception was it, and what was the stacktrace)?  Did something else happen, and if so, what?  Simply saying "it didn't work" doesn't help me to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us how you've constructed the string `sql` in your Java code, so I'm going to have to guess.

It seems that `sql` contains your query from `Select *` onwards, without the line `Set @counter := 0 ...`.  I was able to reproduce your output if I set `sql` to this.  Perhaps you've tried putting that `Set` line in the query as well and that generated an error so you took it out?

What you need to do instead is to execute the `Set @counter := 0 ...` line and then run the query.  In other words, replace the lines

```
Connection con = getDbConnObj();
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery( sql );
printRsLast(rs);
```

with

```
Connection con = getDbConnObj();
Statement st = con.createStatement();
st.execute("Set @counter := 0 ...");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery( sql );
printRsLast(rs);
```

I made this modification to your code and it generated the output you wanted.

Comment: ... and remember to enable `AllowMultiQueries` when opening the connection.

Comment: @GordThompson: I didn't need to do this.  Why do you think I did?

Comment: Because my [test code](https://pastebin.com/A2mXmUUR) would fail if I left `AllowMultiQueries` at its default value (false). (IIRC, it was a SQL Syntax error.)

Comment: @GordThompson: I tried putting `allowMultiQueries` in my test code, and combining the two SQL strings, but that gave me an error `ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.`.  I wasn't aware of the `getMoreResults()` method, which might have fixed that error.  However, that method is perhaps a slightly more 'exotic' part of the JDBC API, and considering the asker looks not to be hugely experienced with JDBC it's probably better to stick to the 'core' API, which I tried to do in my answer.